# How to retain EditText values between fragments

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments

I am a novice in Android development. I am currently working in fragments. So basically I am having two fragments each have their own Edittext and buttons. On back press between fragments works fine but when using the button to move to the next fragment the second fragment fails to hold the edit text value. I tried OnSavedInstance it doesn't help me.

**FirstFragment.kt**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn1).setOnClickListener {
            ediText1 = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et1).text.toString()
            Toast.makeText(activity?.baseContext,ediText1,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_firstFragment_to_secondFragment)
        }
        return view
    }
```

**SecondFragment.kt**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.let {
        param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
        param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
    }
}
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false)

    view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn2).setOnClickListener {
        ediText2 = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et2).text.toString()
        Toast.makeText(activity?.baseContext,ediText2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_secondFragment_to_thirdFragment) }

    return view
}
```

Comment: Seems you need to also put the set arguments in `onSaveInstanceState()` as well, and get the arguments value in `onViewCreated()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to retain the values, most easy is to use [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) , since you are using Navigation Components , ViewModel can be scoped to navGraph , see [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#share_ui-related_data_between_destinations_with_viewmodel)